# is there any way to implement keyboard accessibility (arrow up & down key events ) for flutter web

Tags: flutter

i want to build keyboard accessibility to flutter web, i have used a listile property where i have 5 values(title and subtitle) and i want to access the 5 listile via arrow up and down keys(when clicked on arrow up it should move up and when clicked arrow down key it should move down just like dropdown list), i tried it but unable to do that. Help me to resolve this issue.

```
Material( 
  type: MaterialType.transparency, 
  elevation: 5, 
  child: Container( 
    color: Colors.amber.shade100, 
    width: 288, 
    child: Column(
       children: [ 
        Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 8), 
           width: 288,
            height: 56, 
            decoration: BoxDecoration( 
              border: Border.all( color: Colors.grey, width: 3)),
               child: Row( 
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
                 children: [ SizedBox( width: 219, height: 56, 
                 child: TextFormField(

                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Going to?",
                      
                    ),
                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 20,
                   
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            width: 2)),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 10,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.close,
                        size: 20,
                        
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                  
                      hideOverlay();
                   
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: location.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: 
                         
                         Colors.amber.shade50,
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    
                    tileColor: 
                         Colors.grey,
                       
                    title: Text(
                      location[index].title,
                      
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      location[index].subtitle,
                      
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      
                    
                        controller.text = location[index].title;
                        hideOverlay();
                        focusNode.unfocus();
                        hoveredindex[index] = false;
                      
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }),
         
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can handle the keyboard key easily.

Wrap your returned widget with `RawKeyboardListener` widget.

```
autofocus: true,
focusNode: FocusNode(),
onKey: (event) {
  if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown)) {
     //add your logic here
  }
},
```

[image]